# Referencing an id from separate XUL files

Tags: javascript, xul

If I have two different XUL files, is it possible for the javascript in one to reference a XUL id that is defined in the other? I want to use javascript in a separate xul file to edit the XUL in another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do reference any JS files inside a XUL file & It will be the same If you want to the same JS files in another XUL file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"href="chrome://hello/skin/browserOverlay.css" ?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM
  "chrome://hello/locale/browserOverlay.dtd">

<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://hello/content/browserOverlay.js" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://hello/content/javaLoader.js" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://hello/content/window.js" />

</overlay>
```

If you want to use JS inside XUL, it's possible but in this case you can't link this JS functions to another XUL.

Type this inside the XUL file:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
<![CDATA[
    // your code here
]]>
</script>
```

I would recommend to use JS files separately & you can link them to any number of XUL files as I explained above.

References : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension
             https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for are [XUL overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Overlays). These overlays can be [registered in your `chrome.manifest` file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#overlay) and will allow applying modifications to other XUL documents. For example, most Firefox extensions register an overlay for `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` (the main browser window).